# how to depricate repeated field values from my view?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views

[image]

Look at my screenshot i don't need repeated employee id and name...i
 just want to print emloyee id and name once but i want to display the others records with blank employee id and name but not salary, month and year....I am using JOIN
 query in my hook view... So gyus please suggest me any trick to remove
 those field value...

edited question for clarity...

Answer (score 1):

> You can apply GROUP BY or DISTINCT by enabling views aggregation
>   settings to remove duplicate records.
>
> 1. Go and edit your view
> 2. In Advanced » OTHER section by enabling Use aggregation: Yes
> 3. In FIELDS or FILTER CRITERIA section, select and apply Aggregation settings for which fields you want to group by or distinct.

source: https://www.drupal.org/node/1704962

Comment: distinct and aggregation not solving my problem....if i am applying distintct my whole rows getting depricated..